# Random Failures - Webform City and State Enrichment with Google Location API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, webforms

I do not have much experience with programming and am looking for help figuring out why city and state webform fields are not getting populated by the google location api script when a form submits.  We have about a 30% failure rate and don't appear to be hitting any api call limits and this is not due to invalid postal codes.  Can't figure out what the issue is.

**Background:**
We have forms on our sites with these visible fields:

- Name
- Email
- Postal Code
- Country (picklist)

And these hidden fields (to be populated by a call from a script on the page):

- City
- State

**The basic process we are looking for is:**

When the user enters into the form a Postal Code length greater than or equal to 5 AND Country is not empty THEN call to google's location api and populate the forms hidden fields with City and State.

**Here are the scripts we are using:**

**Script placed in Head:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Script place before the body end tag:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' >

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get city/state only if country has been selected and postal code is at least
    // 5 characters long
    $('#PostalCode,#Country').change(function() {
      var postalCode = $('#PostalCode').val();
      var countryCode = $('#Country option:selected').val();
      if (postalCode.length >= 5 && countryCode !== '') {
        getResponse(postalCode);
      }
    });
})

function getResponse(postalCode) {
  var apiKey = 'OurAPIkeyIshere';
  var baseUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&key=`;
  var countryCode = $('#Country option:selected').val();
  var componentFilter = `&components=country:${ countryCode }|postal_code:${ postalCode }&`;
  var date = new Date();
  var dateTime = `&_=${ date.getTime() }`;
  var url = baseUrl + apiKey + componentFilter + dateTime;

  $.support.cors = true;
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
    var getStatus = response.status;
    if (getStatus === 'OK') {
      getCityState(response.results[0].address_components);
    }
  });
}

function getCityState(addressComponents) {
  var city, state, nbhd, subLoc = '';
  var hasCity, hasPostalTown, hasSubLoc = false;

  $.each(addressComponents, function(index, addressComponent) {
    var types = addressComponent.types;
    $.each(types, function(index, type) {
      switch(type) {
        case 'postal_town':
          postalTown = addressComponent.long_name;
          hasPostalTown = true;
          break;
        case 'locality':
          city = addressComponent.long_name;
          hasCity = true;
          break;
        case 'sublocality':
          subLoc = addressComponent.long_name;
          hasSubLoc = true;
          break;
        case 'neighborhood':
          nbhd = addressComponent.long_name;
          break;
        case 'administrative_area_level_1':
          state = addressComponent.short_name;
          break;
      }
    });
  });

  // set the city
  if(hasPostalTown) {
    $('#City').val(postalTown);
  } else if(hasCity) {
    $('#City').val(city);
  } else if(hasSubLoc) {
    $('#City').val(subLoc);
  } else {
    $('#City').val(nbhd);
  }

  // set the state
  $('#State').val(state);

  // reset flags
  hasCity = false;
  hasPostalCode = false;
  hasSubLoc = false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: did you check if you API call doesnt timeout... do you wait for the API response before you submit the form?

Comment: We did check that and that doesn't seem to be it unfortunately.  We don't wait for the API response before submission are are working on a promises based script with one of our developers to see if that helps.